# Client is using Softaculous to upgrade WordPress versions. How do I upgrade from the WordPress dashboard?

Tags: upgrade

My client is using Softaculous for software upgrading. I tried upgrading from the WordPress dashboard and it wouldn't let me. Do I have to somehow "uninstall" Softaculous for this to work?

Comment: When you say it "wouldn't let" you: what actually happened? Did you get any error messages or other feedback? If so: what?

Comment: It just hangs at "Downloading update from..." and I have to click another part of the dashboard to get out of it. No changes are made.

Comment: Are you positive that the problem is Softaculous?

Comment: No, I am not positive. However, this is a brand new installation of WordPress and that was the only thing I could think of. I've never had this problem before and I've installed WordPress numerous times.

Comment: If your client is *using* Softaculous to manage it's Wordpress installation, then you *should* update it therein: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19783/install-wordpress-on-your-own-server-with-softaculous/ - It looks like you're just gettting network timeouts which might be limited by the host for configuration reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Softaculous doesnt configure anything in WordPress which would stop a Manual Upgrade.
You can contact the support team and they should help you.
To test your claim I just upgraded my Blog which was installed by Softaculous and it is working.
You should check for the PHP error logs as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply upgrade WordPress using Softaculous :

> #### [How to upgrade installations](http://softaculous.com/docs/How_to_upgrade_installations)
>
> This page will guide you in Upgrading the Scripts and getting the latest version available by Softaculous.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to talk to your client's host. The problem could be a server configuration issue, or it could be a problem with how Softaculous configures WordPress.

A quick Google search doesn't turn up any obvious problems with using the core upgrade mechanism with Softaculous-installed WordPress. You might need to reference one of these Codex entries:

- [Upgrading WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress)
- [Changing File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [manually updating Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update)?

You can also try [removing the .maintenance file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Step_1.5%3a_Remove_.maintenance_file) from your WordPress directory.